# My message box cuts off the last message in the list

Tags: css

I am very new to CSS.

I was working on this little chat site, but I noticed that the latest message was always missing. It seems my message box cuts off the last message but I can't fix it.

I tried changing the `height` value of the messages `div` but that didn't help.

So, this code gives you my HTML and the styling (in the `<style>` tag) but I really don't know what to do now. I don't want to resize the box or it'll look ugly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;
        }

        form {
            background: #000;
            padding: 3px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        form input {
            border: 0;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 90%;
            margin-right: 0.5%;
        }

        form button {
            width: 9%;
            background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
            border: none;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #messages {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #messages div {
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }

        #messages div:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #eee;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>

    <form id="msgForm" action="">
        <input type="text" name="msg">
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
    
    <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="lolz"/>

    <div id="messages">

    </div>
    <script defer>
        const socket = io("localhost:3000")
        const messages = document.getElementById('messages')
        const msgForm = document.getElementById('msgForm')

        const nick = document.getElementById('lolz')

        socket.on('message', (nick, msg) => {
            appendMessages(nick, msg)
        })
        socket.on('output-messages', data => {
            console.log(data)
            if (data.length) {
                data.forEach(message => {
                    appendMessages(message.nick, message.msg)
                })
            }
        })

        msgForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
                e.preventDefault()
                if (msgForm && msgForm.msg && msgForm.msg.value && nick && nick.value) {
                    socket.emit('chatmessage', nick.value, msgForm.msg.value)
                }
                msgForm.msg.value = ''
        })

        function appendMessages(nick, message) {
            const html = `<div><strong>${nick}</strong>: ${message}</div>`
            messages.innerHTML += html
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, you can see what it looks like:
[image: e: e (x2)]

It's supposed to show this message:

"**e**: I hate this box!"

Comment: would be good to get the javascript too

Comment: Seems like if i put some divs on messages div, they work as expected. Probably js will have the problem as mentioned above.

Comment: I've added the JS now

Comment: A security note: I noticed your functions do not sanitize their inputs. I really do not know if this is just some example/draft code but it looks like it's vulnerable to XSS attacks; I'm not really an expert, but if needed, good strategies to prevent possible vulnerabilities are documented here https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/ and here https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: Oh thats good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `position: fixed` property for the `form` element.

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> `fixed`
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.

Basically it means that the element is in a different layer, so it will *overlap* the rest of the content on the page and can possibly hide elements under it.

What you want is `position: sticky`.

I suggest you to read more on the great MDN documentation site:

- CSS: position
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
- Sticky footers
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Sticky_footers
- The stacking context
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: If I use this, then the bar doesn't float with the page so people can't see what they're typing.

Comment: I'll have a look at the docs though.

Comment: Ohhh! I had to add `top: 20px` (or whatever)